# Convergence in probability of a random series

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\sum_{k\geq 1}|a_k|<\infty.$ If $\{X_k,k\geq 1\}$ are all independent with $\mathbf{E}(X_k)=0$ for all $k$ and $\sup_{k\geq 1}\text{Var}(X_k)<\infty$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n a_kX_k$$ converges in probability.

---

My attempt: I first attempted to exploit the characteristic function of the partial sum $\varphi_{\sum_{k=1}^n a_kX_k}(t)=\prod_{k=1}^n \varphi_{X_k}(t/a_k)$, and arguing that the ch.f converges to some ch.f of a constant, since converging in distribution to a constant is equivalent to converging in probability to the constant, but how should I proceed here? Does anyone have ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: let $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^na_kX_k$. By computing and then bounding $\mathbb E\left[\left(S_n-S_m\right)^2\right]$, we can show that $\left(S_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb L^2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Take $a_n=\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ and $X_n=n$. If $X_n$'s are i.i.d. then $\sum E|a_kX_k| =E|X_1| \sum |a_k| <\infty$ which implies that $\sum a_kX_k$ conveges absolutely with probability $1$.

Answer for the revised version: $\sum E(|a_k| |X_k|) \leq \sum |a_k|\sqrt {E|X_k|^{2})}<\infty$ so the series converges absolutely with probability $1$. Independence is not required and we actaully get a.s. convergence (which is stronger than convergence in probability).

Comment: I fixed the error of the question. Could you answer the revised question?